# Optimization reading from database

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, h2

I need to  check in database exist ~2k records, I test id on db size 1.000.000 and it takes 46s. Its too long, because in future this db can have more than 500.000.000 records. Is any way to speed up searching from db ? I use JDBC in java, here's code :

```
public int search(List<String> toSearch) throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM strings where string =  ?";
    StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder(query);
    for (int i=0; i<toSearch.size()-1; i++) {
        sB.append("OR string=?");
    }
    System.out.println(toSearch.size());

    PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement(sB.toString());
    
    int i=1;
    for (String string : toSearch) {
        prep.setString(i, string);
        i++;
    }
    long data = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ResultSet resultSet = prep.executeQuery();
    long data2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((data2 - data) / 1000);
    List<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {

        toReturn.add(resultSet.getString("string"));

    }
    return toReturn.size();

}
```

Table name is strings, column string.

Comment: Do you wanna continue with h2? it will not be a good choice for a large amount of data. Try MySQL and then have a procedure in the db itself

Comment: SQL query length has some limits. Try to solve this by using a batch of 100 elements for instance. In this case you could even introduce more than one thread reading the database.

Comment: Imagine you have table `strings`. Now insert the `ids` in a new temp table and try to join both tables.

Comment: Better try Postgres instead of MySQL

Comment: And do `SELECT string FROM strings ...` as a smaller ResultSet is faster too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to have an index on `string` column.

```sql
CREATE INDEX indexName ON strings(string);
```

Do not construct queries with variable number of arguments for H2. Use

```java
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM strings WHERE string = ANY(?)");
ps.setObject(1, toSearch.toArray(new String[0]));
```

If you use some old unsupported version of H2, use its `TABLE()` function instead as described in documentation distributed with your version (`Prepared Statements and IN(...)` section in PDF).

With other DBMS you may need other tricks to avoid dynamic generation of SQL code, `= ANY(?)` will work in PostgreSQL and its forks and in H2, but not in other DBMS.